# Remove the Anchor icon in Docky

Tags: dock, customization, docky

Can I remove the Anchor icon from my Docky dock?

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this. I think it is supposed to stay for access to your prefs.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In order to remove the anchor icon from docky, you must first upgrade to the most recent version. To do this, you need to add the development [PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) to your list of software sources. On Ubuntu 9.10 and later, you may do this by typing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:docky-core/ppa
```

and then refreshing the list of packages with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This may not trigger the update, in which case you should open Synaptic package manager, and search for docky. Finding the docky package, select it and use the menu item Package->Force Version. This will let you select the version of docky to install. The fix to remove the anchor icon requires version 1.0 **or later**.

Once you have the **Docky-Core PPA version installed** (the latest version is 2.2 against the 2.0.6 you find on the default repository), you may disable the docky icon by:

1. Open [gconf-editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor) by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and typing `gconf-editor`.
2. Navigate to `apps/docky-2/docky/items/DockyItem`.
3. Deselect the `ShowDockyItem` key.
4. Restart docky.

After you have disabled your anchor icon, you may still access your docky preferences by right clicking any dividers you may have on the dock.

Comment: The final instructions are the same as gamerchick02's, but its very important that you have the latest version of docky installed to do this.

Comment: I thought this would be a cool thing to do, so I tried it out... it took me a while to figure out how to get the correct version in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I couldn't have figured out the "upgrade to the most recent version" part.

Comment: Great answer Zoe, I have been passively trying to figure out how to remove the anchor icon for a few days. This worked!

Comment: Like Matthew said below, you need to add the PPA repository even if you have a newer version. And it's simpler to just [follow his answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4942/remove-the-anchor-icon-in-docky/18163#18163), since we need to open the terminal anyway.

Comment: I've personally never liked giving instructions on how to do things using large blocks of shell commands. It may be much simpler and more concise, but for people unfamiliar with the system, its also intimidating and much more difficult to parse the actual actions.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, from an OMG!Ubuntu [article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/04/remove-anchor-icon-from-docky/1.3.4.):

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>
2. Type command [`gconf-editor`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor) and hit enter/return
3. Navigate to `apps/docky-2/docky/items/DockyItem` in the gconf-editor
4. Uncheck `ShowDockyItem`
5. Restart `Docky`

Hope that helps.  Also, see the Launchpad [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/docky/+bug/500185) that addresses the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the +1. I figured the bug report would help the OP.

Answer (score 6):

Run these three commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:docky-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
gconftool-2 --type bool --set /apps/docky-2/Docky/Items/DockyItem/ShowDockyItem false
```

This does the exact the same thing as Zoe's answer (add the PPA, upgrade to the latest version, and hide the anchor item), but all automatically. You will have to restart Docky after you finish.

Comment: As per your comment, neither updating Docky to 2.2 by adding the PPA nor running `gconftool` to force adding that setting into gconf-editor hided the Docky icon.

Answer (score 0):

`gconftool-2 --type Boolean --set /apps/docky-2/Docky/Items/DockyItem/ShowDockyItem False`

and restart Docky. Set final value to `True` to turn it back on. Worked fine for me on 12.10. [Source](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/04/remove-anchor-icon-from-docky)