# Docky doesn't let me hide the starter

Tags: 10.10, docky

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove the Anchor icon in Docky](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4942/remove-the-anchor-icon-in-docky)

When i try to use docky in maverick, the option in Settings to hide the starter for this dock let me untick even though it's active? Someone has an workaround. Where is the configuration file for the docks, perhaps i can switch it in there?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you have the latest version of Docky installed? "*The fix to remove the anchor icon requires version 1.0 or later.*" That question is here too: [Remove the Anchor icon in Docky](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4942/remove-the-anchor-icon-in-docky)

Comment: yes, it occures in the version from universe as well as in 2.1.0~bzr1653-0ubuntu1~10.10~dockycore1