# How to remove additional docky panels?

Tags: ubuntu-mate, docky

I installed dockey and cannot remove the additional panels added via the Delete button. Is there a way to remove additional panels?

Comment: Why the `mint` tag?

Comment: Yeah, It should be Mate as I'm running on Mate Desktop.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer on [Remove second empty Docky?](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1566953&p=10450008#post10450008)

> - Upgrade to the latest Docky version
> - Press Alt + F2
> - Run `gconf-editor`
> - Navigate to *apps/docky-2/docky/DockController/ActiveDocks*
> - Remove the second dock
> - Restart Docky

See also [Remove the Anchor icon in Docky](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4942/remove-the-anchor-icon-in-docky).

Comment: You have copied instructions from 2011. Are you sure they're still applicable now?

Comment: it worked for my ubuntu 17.10.